# Powershell: combine contents of strings with dots inbetween, ignore empty ones

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

Our naming convention consists of the first name, insertion, and lastname, all separated by dots. An example:

- Stack Overflow = Stack.Overflow
- Stack over Flow = Stack.over.flow

These outputs will be used later on in the script for the creation of a mailbox, user account, etc.

I've successfully combined the values of all strings by simply plus-ing them together, like this:

```
$Convention = $Firstname+"."+$Insertion+"."+$LastName
```

The values for these strings come from information being put in when the stript runs (Read-Host "....")

Now, I'm struggling with making this more dynamic. Of course, not every person has an insertion in their name. Using the given example, the current output of $Convention would be "Stack..Overflow", instead of "Stack.Overflow".

My question to you is: how can I filter out both, the $Insertion **and** the extra dot, when $Insertion is empty? It's most likely something very simple, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Thanks in advance for any given help!

Kr,
Robbert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do

```
$Convention = ('{0}.{1}.{2}' -f $Firstname, $Insertion, $LastName) -replace '\.+', '.'
```

The `-replace` uses regex in the first parameter, so `'\.+', '.'` means to replace *1 or more consecutive dots* by a single dot.

Alternatively you could use regex `\.{2,}` which reads *two or more consecutive dots*

Example:

```
$Firstname  = 'Robbert'
$Insertion  = ''
$LastName   = 'Verwaart'
$Convention = ('{0}.{1}.{2}' -f $Firstname, $Insertion, $LastName) -replace '\.+', '.'
```

Output:

```
Robbert.Verwaart
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Theo! This indeed does the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code below will go through each of your `$convention` array, if this is an array, and test if the insertion is empty. If the `$Insertion` variable is empty, the `$i` will remove the `$Insertion` variable and the extra `.`. You need to add this into the script as a test, before creating the mailboxes.

```
foreach ($i in $convention){
    if($insertion -eq "" -or $insertion -eq $null) {
        $i= $Firstname+"."+$LastName
    } else {
        continue
    }
}
```